# Create a team using a team template via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Can anyone enlighten me on the Graph API endpoint to create a team using a team template. The [create team endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0) does exist but Im looking for the endpoint that allows me to create a team from an existing team (aka [Team template](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-AMA/Team-Templates/td-p/120528) )

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. Its a [clone operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, creating a team from a template and cloning a team from an existing team are two different things.

Teams Templates are currently only available in the beta endpoint and not supported in production. You can use the ones listed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/get-started-with-teams-templates

On the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams endpoint, you can create a Team from a template by providing the chosen template in the request body:

```
$body = @{
            "template@odata.bind" = "$targetTemplate"
            "displayName"         = "Test Team DisplayName"
            "description"         = "Description"
}
```

$targetTemplate being one of the values from the documentation above, for example: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationStaff').

Cloning a team is done using the supported in production v1.0 endpoint:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0 where you have to specify from which team and which parts you want to clone:

```
$body = @{  
     "displayName": "My Test Team",
     "description": "New Description",
     "mailNickname": "TestTeam2",
     "partsToClone": "apps,tabs,settings,channels,members",
     "visibility": "private"
}
```